# OOP - Best way to populate Object

Tags: oop, solid-principles

I try to follow OOP and S.O.L.I.D for my code and came across a topic where I'm not sure what's the best way to align it with OOP.

When I have an Object with different properties, what's the ideal way to populate those properties?

1. Should the Object if possible populate them?
2. Should separate code assign the values to the properties?

I have the following example (Python), which I created based on how I think is the best way.

The Object has methods that will populate the properties so if you instantiate the Object, in this case an Account with and Id, it should automatically populate the properties since they can be retrieved with the ID using DB and API.

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, account_id):
        self.id = account_id
        self.name = None
        self.page = Page(self.id)

    def populate(self):
        self.get_name()

    def get_name(self):
        ''' Code to retrieve Account name from DB with account_id '''
        self.name = <NAME>

class Page:
    def __init__(self, account_id):
        self.id = 0
        self.name = None
        self.user_count = 0

        self.populate()

    def populate():
        self.get_id()
        self.get_name()
        self.get_user_count()

    def get_id(self):
        ''' Code to retrieve Page Id from DB with account_id '''
        self.id = <Page_ID>

    def get_name(self):
        ''' Code to retrieve Account name from DB with account_id '''
        self.name = <NAME>

    def get_user_count(self):
        ''' Code to retrieve user_count from API with page_id '''
        self.user_count = <user_count>
```

So instead of doing something like:

```
account = Account()
account.id = 1
account.name = function.to.get.account.name()
account.page = Page()
account.page.id = 1
```

I will have it managed by the class itself.

The problem I could see with this is the dependency on the DB and API classes/methods which go against S.O.L.I.D (D - Dependency Inversion Principle) as I understand.

For me it makes sense to have the class handle this, today I have some similar code that would describe the Object and then populate the Object properties in a separate Setup class, but I feel this is unnecessary.

The articles I found for OOP/S.O.L.I.D did not cover this and I didn't really find any explanation on how to handle this with OOP.

Thanks for your help!
Michael

Comment: Have you read about delegation?

Comment: @aryamccarthy Not yet, will have a look, thanks!

Comment: After reading about delegation I don't feel like this is relevant to my question here. "An object could delegate responsibility of a message it couldn't handle to objects that potentially could (its delegates)." But the object could handle everything, so based on that do I understand correctly that the Object should handle everything it can?

Answer (score 0):

Your design seems fairly ok. Try having a look @ Builder Pattern and Composite pattern. And for your question on violation of D principle.

> The problem I could see with this is the dependency on the DB and API classes/methods which go against S.O.L.I.D (D - Dependency Inversion Principle) as I understand.

The dependencies are already abstracted into separate components I guess. It is the responsibility of that component to give the data you needed per the contract. Your implementation should be independent of the what that component internally does. A DAO layer for accessing DB and Data APIs can help you achieve this.

The dependency then your system will have is the DAO component. That can be injected with different ways. There are frameworks available to help you here or you can control the creation of objects and injections when needed with some combinations of factory, builder and singleton patterns. If it is single DB instance or LogFile you may also consider using Singleton to get the component.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In looking at SOLID and OOP the key is to analyze what it is your doing and separate out the various elements to make sure that they do not end up mixed together.  If they do the code tends to become brittle and difficult to change.

Looking at the Account class several questions need to be answered when considering the SOLID principles.  The first is what is the responsibility of the Account class?  The Single Responsibility Principle would say there should be one and only one reason for it to change.  So does the Account class exist to retrieve the relevant information from the DB or does it exist for some other purpose?  If for some other purpose then it has multiple responsibilities and the code should be refactored so that the class has a single responsibility.

With OOP typically when retrieving data from a DB a repository class is used to retrieve information from the DB for an object.  So in this case the code that is used to retrieve information from the DB would be extracted out form the Account class and put in this repository class: AccountRepository.

Dependency Inversion means that the Account class should not depend explicitly on the AccountRepository class, instead the Account class should depend on the abstraction.  The abstraction would be an interface or abstract class with no implementation.  In this case we could use an interface called IAccountRepository.  Now the Account class could use either an IoC container or a factory class to get the repository instance while only having knowledge of IAccountRepository